# How to count non zero rows in a N-d tensor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I need to find the number of non zero rows and put them in a 1D tensor(kind of vector).

For an example:

```
tensor = [
    [
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0],
        [4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ],
    [
        [4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ],
    [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]
]
```

the tensor shape will be `[None,45,7]` in a real application, but here it is `[3,2,7]`.

So I need to find the number of non-zero rows in dimension 1 and keep them in a 1d tensor.

`non_zeros = [2,1,1] #result for the above tensor`

I need to do it in `TensorFlow`, if it is in `NumPy`, I would have done it.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
t = tf.math.not_equal(tensor, 0)
t = tf.reduce_any(t, -1)
t = tf.cast(t, tf.int32)
t = tf.reduce_sum(t, -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`tf.math.count_nonzero`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/count_nonzero) combined with [`tf.reduce_sum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_sum)

```
>>> tf.math.count_nonzero(tf.reduce_sum(tensor,axis=2),axis=1)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([2, 1, 1])>
```